# Timeouts for multiple clients in Java

Tags: java, architecture, software-design

I have one Server and multiple clients. With some period, clients sends an alive packet to Server. (At this moment, Server doesn't respond alive packets). The period may change device to device and configurable at runtime, for both Server and Clients. I want to generate an alert when one or more clients doesn't send the alive packet. (One packet or two in row etc.). This aliveness is used other parts of application so the quicker notice is the better. I came up some ideas but I couldn't select one.

1. Create a task that checks every clients last alive packet timestamps with current time and generate alert or alerts. Call this method in some period which should be smaller than minimum client-period.

   Actually that seems better to me, however this way unnecessarily I check some clients alive. (Ex: If clients period are change 1-5 minute, task should be run in every minute at least, so I check all clients above 2 minute period is redundant). Also if the minimum of client periods is decrease, I should decrease the tasks period also.
2. Create a task for each clients, and check the last alive packet timestamps with current time, sleep for one client's period time.

   In this way, if clients number goes very high, there will be dozens of task. Since they will sleep most of the time, I still doubt this is more elegant.

Is there any idiom or pattern for this kind of situation? I think `watchdog` kind implementation is suite well, however I didn't see something like in `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 2 is not very useful as it is vague idea to write 100 task for 100 clients.
Approach 1 can be optimized if you use average client-period instead of minimum.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.
Is it critical if alert is generated few seconds later (or earlier) than it should be?
If not then maybe it's worth grouping clients with nearby heartbeat intervals and run the check against not a single client but the group of clients? This will allow to decrease number of tasks (100 -> 10) and increase number of clients handled by single task (1 -> 10).

Answer (score 0):

First approach is fine.

Only thing I can suggest you is that create an independent service to do this control. If you set this task as a thread in your server, it wouldn't be that manageable. Imagine your control thread is broken, killed etc, how would you notice? So, build an independent OS service, another java program, to check last alive timestamps periodically.

In this way you can easily modify and restart your service and see its logs separately. According to its importance, you may even built a "watchdog of watchdog" service too.